# How to apply a loop cut on a specific area on a big object?

Tags: objects, edit-mode

I am trying to put a loop cut on the rectangle in the middle of the screen, but it's trying to put a loop cut on the whole thing.
[image]
And that's not what I want.

Comment: if the objects have nothing "in common", the loop cut should work as you expect:
https://imgur.com/a/PQ0qWlE

Comment: Well it's all been extruded from 1 object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend selecting all the faces of the object you want to put details on and hitting "P" to separate it as another object. 
This will help you with 2 things:
1) It will allow you to duplicate this object across the scene
2) And it will keep your large mesh clean and separate from the small details.

Ideally, you want your scene to have no unnecessary loop cuts or geometry.

Select faces, Hit P

[image]

Now you can create a loop cut for your small object, but there is also a new object in your collection.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Can i assume that you essentially want to cut only a certain face, as loop cut (name says it already) cuts in a continuous loop as many connected faces as it can.

If you only want to cut a certain face and do not want to use the knife tool, then there is a easy solution:

1. Go in face select mode and select the faces bordering on the face you want to cut, then press <kbd>H</kbd> to hide those faces. Or you can just select the face you want to cut and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to invert the selection and then press <kbd>H</kbd>.
2. Now you either have only that face left and can cut it however you want, or there is a gap separating the face from the rest and thus limiting the loop cut from going all around.
3. After the cut is done and you want to see the rest of the object again, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and they are visible again.

Here a visual helper showing the 2 ways mentioned:
[image]

Happy blending.